# Google search listing shows My google+ profile details and not my website details

Tags: seo

I am new comer to Website creation and now i need to list my website in Google search, Everything is going fine,
i.e., My website is being shown in Google results(Only when i request as "androidcoaching.com") ,
but for other general search like ("android coaching" or "android coaching in chennai") search results  showing  Google + profile and not website details .

Guide me to show my website details and not Google+ details

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Although this isn't really the forum for a complete SEO walkthrough there is one more thing to take into account when searching.

Remember that if you are **logged in to Google**, your search results will be augmented to show more of the sites you are connected to.

To get a *true* representation of your search rankings, make sure you are not logged in to your Google account or you may find that your previous searches, Google+ account and links shared by those in your Google+ circles or people who have contacted you through GMail are also showing in positions that they do not hold when other users search.

As for getting ranked, there are many angles to take from making sure the structure of a website is correctly formatted (header tags, etc), creating more information rich and useful content and gaining **quality links back from credible sources** - of which there are many useful sources online.

Answer (score -1):

The First Reason is You didn't optimized your title tags and meta description 
add a good tittle tag and meta tag descriptions
and you must include Chennai Key Word in tittle tag(didn't include Chennai word )with keywords.
second : You got to do homepage optimization better by using best search keywords.